# Edit history may become out of order if suggested edit was approved with improvements

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, revisions-list

For some reason, [the history of a tag wiki with a suggested edit approved with improvements from the reviewer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/139621/revisions) may be listed out of order:

[image: Tag wiki history with out-of-order edits]

This can prove confusing when the edit history is reviewed.  Is this normal?

This happens with questions as well: in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11487637/revisions), revision 3 appears before revision 2, and after posting the improvement, the rendered HTML for the question was that of the suggested edit, not that of the improvement. Furthermore, an edit by the improver in the 5-minute grace window was counted as a separate edit (which showed up in the right order).

Comment: The funny is that the numbers are correct. `:)` It is not normal, and it is the first time I see this.

Comment: This isn't specific to tag wikis. The rendering is wrong, too. This is definitely a new bug from yesterday.

Comment: Here's another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482747/how-many-queries-does-google-allow-from-a-specified-ip-or-website you don't see the last revision unless you edit or see the history

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A fix for this will be deployed in the next push.  Thanks for the report!

Comment: Users can still see the edits out of order, but now with the numbering correctly ordered, see [Suggested edit comes after the improved one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140233)

Comment: @Geoff, I've run across this twice in the last few days (well, really, both times that I cared to check). [Occurrence 1](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14308088/revisions) and [occurrence 2](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14350126/revisions). Ignore the edits I'll likely make now in revision 5 of the first occurrence.

Comment: And actually, as I look at it - some of the changes attributed to me in revision 2 of the second occurrence, I made, and some, I didn't. And intelis made *none* of the changes in revision 3. It's all pretty confused, really.

Comment: This is an issue (again), as @MichaelPetrotta said: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6169/edit-history-messed-up-when-improving-a-suggested-edit — and here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7852756#7852756