# After improving an edit, question shows new version, edit shows old version

Tags: support, bug, revisions-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit history may become out of order if suggested edit was approved with improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139625/edit-history-may-become-out-of-order-if-suggested-edit-was-approved-with-improve)

I recently improved an edit suggested on [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20973/quick-look-at-how-much-ram-is-allocated-to-sql-server/20975#20975). The edit can be [seen here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/20975/revisions), and is reflected in the current version of the answer. I decided to improve the edit and left the checkbox "this edit was helpful" checked, since it was in fact helpful and made me realize that I left out some information.

However, when I go to edit the question now, the edit box shows the *old* version of the answer. Well, more specifically, the version of the answer that included only the suggested edit, not the version that the answer reflects now, which includes my improvement. I noticed that on the revisions page the suggested edit is marked as revision 3, and my edit is revision 2, even though my edit is reflected in the current version. They seem to be listed in the wrong order.

Why does the edit option now show me an obsolete version of the answer, and the public site show me a different revision? Why are the revisions sorted out of order?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the ordering of revisions to me...

Comment: I wonder if while you were "improving", other people approved the edit and it went through?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Possibly, but there still shouldn't be a scenario where both edits "kind of" won. Either the improvement won or the suggestion won.

Comment: Did you go back using the back button?

Comment: @jcolebrand absolutely not. I've learned to not use browser nav buttons here. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this is an issue provoked by the fact that, both edits have the same timestamp (down to seconds at least).

[image]

Seems like the "system" uses one query method to present the answer and a different one to present the answer revisions.

*Mere speculation, since only developers can fully answer this.*

---

Nonetheless, as seen by the revision ID:

1. answered 5 hours ago by Aaron Bertrand
2. edited 47 mins ago by Aaron Bertrand
3. suggested 47 mins ago by AngryHacker

This tells us that the answer was placed, an edit was made and a suggested edit gone through.

Comment: If I improve a suggested edit, doesn't the improvement inherit the same timestamp as the suggestion? I don't think the person who suggested the edit came in and modified their suggestion as I was improving it. I suppose it is feasible that the suggestion was approved at the exact same second as my edit, the suggestion was at `edit(0)` when I improved it, and it only took me about 10 seconds to improve. So it seems possible but unlikely.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Possible nonetheless... I believe that developers will pronounce themselves as to clarify what happened.

Comment: Yes, possible. I'm holding off on a further edit to the answer in question to leav it in its current stat for the devs, but I'm not sure how long I'll have to wait. :-)

Comment: I bet they don't use an `ORDER BY`...

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140240/165455), this was due to a bug and the fix is being rolled out soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other example, where I just improved a proposed edit.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11524960/revisions

Even though I just corrected one word in the edit (and removed the Thank you), the diff shows that I did the bulk of the edit, which I did not. The revision numbers are also reversed.

Definitely a problem.