# Suggested edit comes after the improved one

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

I just improved a suggest edit and, when viewing the [revision log of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11540949/revisions), I see the suggested edit **after** the improved one. I usually see it before since the *improver* do the edit after the *suggester*.

[image]

It's not a big problem but it might be a bit confusing.

Comment: Looks like [Edit history may become out of order if suggested edit was approved with improvements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139625) is back and/or hasn't been rolled out yet in full.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140020/after-improving-an-edit-question-shows-new-version-edit-shows-old-version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug introduced by ordering the suggested edits by creation date.  A fix has been pushed and will be deployed soon.

Comment: Yep this is fixed right now, thanks !

Comment: On SU (rev 2012.7.21.3438), clicking "edit" for [this](http://superuser.com/q/452066) question [gets one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2f5j4.png) the suggested version (from chx) **in the editor**, not the improved one (from Mokubai). The order in [the revisions](http://superuser.com/posts/452066/revisions) looks [okay](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6nQbv.png) though. But even there, clicking "edit" next to Mokubai's version gets one chk's version, also shown [in the dropdown then](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YSTwp.png). Both "38 minutes ago" tooltips show the exact same timestamp, 2012-07-22 10:16:40Z.

Comment: Here's another one where clicking edit gives one the old revision: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482747/how-many-queries-does-google-allow-from-a-specified-ip-or-website (Kudos to [a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139625/edit-history-may-become-out-of-order-if-suggested-edit-was-approved-with-improve#comment394959_139625) by random.)

Comment: (The SU question has meanwhile been edited, but the SO example still shows the issue.)

Comment: Geoff, more issues that might be related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140926/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-5-minute-grace-period

Comment: Ah, there's a new bug report now: [Edit button shows source of older revision](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140973/edit-button-shows-source-of-older-revision).