# Wrong diff after suggested edit that only changed tags

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review, diff

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/581490/) shows the wrong diff. [The revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7593516/revisions) shows what happened: first william56 suggested a retag, which was approved (revision 2), then Gilles edited the body, title and tags (revision 3). The suggested edit shows the body and title from revision 3, even though the suggested edit was against revision 1.

It is probably relevant that the suggested edit only changed tags. It may also be relevant that I initially clicked “Improve” on the suggested edit; then, when I was [blocked from submitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145565/improving-a-suggested-edit-that-has-been-approved-in-the-meantime-leads-to-a-dea) because the retag had been approved, I went to the post and used the edit button.

Comment: This has been reported (and apparently fixed) before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140020/after-improving-an-edit-question-shows-new-version-edit-shows-old-version and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139625/edit-history-may-become-out-of-order-if-suggested-edit-was-approved-with-improve

Comment: @AaronBertrand This is a related but different bug. The examples linked in the previous reports look correct now.

Comment: but is that because they've been manually corrected? Your symptom seems quite similar if not identical. It could be a regression. Anyway I wasn't pointing out the other posts to suggest this was an exact duplicate, but rather to make sure other readers (primarily the devs) see that there have been similar issues in the past, and that they were stated to have been fixed.