# Reviewed suggested edit view for title-only edits takes body of last revision?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, revisions-list, diff

Yesterday I was pointed at some rejected suggested edits. Some of the corrections were valid, so I edited the posts accordingly, while making several further edits. Looking at the suggested edits now however, it seems that for those posts where only changes to the title were originally suggested, the post mortem suggested edit view now incorporates the body of the latest revision. (Or at least it appears like that to me)

Take for example [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2908430). If you take a look at [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18621564/revisions) of that post, you will see my later edits. The edited body seems to have been incorporated in the suggested edit view. For edits where originally changes to the body were suggested, there is no such confusion.

Why does this matter? In the case of some post mortem discussions or explanations it might help to see the actual situation as it was when the edit was suggested. Especially in the case of edits that might be considered too minor.

So have I stumbled upon a bug here?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145566/wrong-diff-after-suggested-edit-that-only-changed-tags (short answer is that suggested edits that don't touch one part of a post - where the parts are title, tags and body - won't store a copy of that part of the post. It is *possible* to retrieve the correct revision, but that apparently isn't done for the postmortem view.)

Comment: Ah, so a known issue @Shog9. Is that worth "fixing" (if it's not too much hassle)? I think there's something to be said for an accurate history.

Comment: I have no idea how much of a hassle this is; IMHO, it's probably worth fixing at *some* point, but not urgent (note that it's been over a year since the first report with little attention paid).

Comment: Fair enough. I merely stumbled upon it because I was going to make a point about a string of suggested edits. This view more or less undermines it to some extent. ;)

Comment: Yes, I definitely see the problem when trying to reconstruct the context for an edit's rejection.