# Diff for an old suggested edit contains more recent text

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, diff

I just noticed that **an old** [approved siggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23676561) for my post contains **a more recent** version of the post after my today edit.

> [image: suggested edit diff]

I free-hand-circled a code from my post that I've added recently. At the time of suggested edit there was another code:

> [image: diff from revisions]

See [revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57153594/revisions) for details.

Comment: I'm speculating here, but it seems that the title edit was implicitly accepted when another user did an "Improve Edit". The edit review is showing the modified title (the only thing that changed) with the current question. If you look at the edit history for the question, the Revision 3 change in question only shows the title, and not the content of the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reviewed suggested edit view for title-only edits takes body of last revision?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196833/reviewed-suggested-edit-view-for-title-only-edits-takes-body-of-last-revision)