# Improve Edit and second edit

Tags: bug, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit history may become out of order if suggested edit was approved with improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139625/edit-history-may-become-out-of-order-if-suggested-edit-was-approved-with-improve)

1. I opened a question from the "newest question" tab.
2. A user without edit priviledges suggested an edit of the question.
3. I chose "improve edit" and made some improvements and saved it.
   After that the post was edited like I did it.
4. I wanted to improve something else and hit the edit button again.
   But now the post's "source" isn't the last edit but the first one.

[That is the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567219/average-number-of-days-using-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this issue was fixed. But maybe it wasn't, or the fix has brought about a slightly different symptom.

[Edit history may become out of order if suggested edit was approved with improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139625/edit-history-may-become-out-of-order-if-suggested-edit-was-approved-with-improve)

For example, when I try to edit [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20973/quick-look-at-how-much-ram-is-allocated-to-sql-server/20975#20975), the edit content does not match what is shown on the page. The "live" version is different, including this line in the last code sample:

```
-- SQL Server 2012:
```

This line is missing in the version the site thinks I should be editing, which doesn't match the live version.

I'm not sure if editing the post again will set everything right, so I'm leaving the post as is in case there is still something to fix.