# Eeeek! What happened to my 5-minute grace period?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, suggested-edits, grace-period

There was recently a question about how improving an edit caused the previous revision to appear when you clicked the edit button again (but I can't find it for some reason). I recently encountered this issue, when I improved an edit and removed the signature from the post. After submitting, I realized I should fix up the first line of the post as well, but didn't notice that the signature was present in the text again (as per the previous revision).

Now what's even worse is it recorded my two edits as separate edits, a mere 16 seconds apart. What happened to my 5 minute grace period!? How on Earth did the system even confuse these two events in order to not grant me the grace period? What happens with edits that it would think 5 minutes have passed? Did it not see me as the same user or something?

So now [**this revision history**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11624329/revisions) is labeled with two revision from me. The first one with two reasons, one changing the first line which resulted in an overall deletion of characters, and the second re-deleting the signature line at the bottom after noticing it had been re-added.

**First edit timestamp:** `2012-07-24 05:02:34Z`

**Second edit timestamp:** `2012-07-24 05:02:50Z`

**Time difference:** `+0000-00-00 00:00:16`

Comment: Do you mean [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140458/)

Comment: Not sure, but I have a feeling it is related to the suggested-improve reverse order bug we had a few days earlier.

Comment: @juergend: I don't think it is a duplicate, but I think the bug is related to that.

Comment: No repro, myself; just made three separate edits to one question (about two minutes apart, total), that were recorded as [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624676/database-pivoting-what-is-the-purpose). But your data looks pretty compelling.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: The error occurred after trying to edit an improvement I made to a suggested edit. It wasn't just a normal edit out of the blue.

Comment: The improved edits being out of order is still an issue indeed, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140233/suggested-edit-comes-after-the-improved-one/140240#comment397479_140240

Comment: Two edits in [the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11624329/revisions) at July 24th 5:02 UTC, but none [in the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11624221/timeline)? ([screen capture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl1LO.png))

Comment: [Another example](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11629107/revisions). The older question you're thinking of may be http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139625/edit-history-may-become-out-of-order-if-suggested-edit-was-approved-with-improve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was related to this issue:  [Edit button shows source of older revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140973/edit-button-shows-source-of-older-revision)

The date and time to check the grace window was from the previous post revision made prior to the suggested edit improvement.