# Rollback to an edit doesn't show exact edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, rollbacks

I edited a question and among other things I changed `corn` to `cron`. Another user also edited the question at about the same time. I thought my edit was better, so I rolled back to my edit, but instead of `cron`, it still says `corn`.

My edit:

[image]

Question after rollback:

[image]

As you can see, the result of the rollback is completely different from my edit. My edit was  useless, because there is no way to get it back. This is quite frustrating.

Not sure if this is relevant, but I was improving a suggested edit and then did a rollback.

[Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11698721)

Comment: Since both of you have the same goal of improving the post, it probably would  have been easier to just submit a second edit and adjust the things that the other editor missed rather than rolling back all changes. Still, this does seem a bit buggy...

Comment: Yeah, something is very broken there.

Comment: @balpha, note that the UTC timestamps are exactly the same. Might be related to [Edit button shows source of older revision](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140973/edit-button-shows-source-of-older-revision) and [Eeeek! What happened to my 5-minute grace period?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140926/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-5-minute-grace-period)

Comment: @jmort253, maybe, but I would have to do it manually again. It's not possible to copy/paste from my original edit, because that has the wrong contents too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug was in fact related to:  [Edit button shows source of older revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140973/edit-button-shows-source-of-older-revision)

Same story but slightly different symptoms.