# Order of revisions in revision history incorrect, when edit was Improved

Tags: bug, revisions-list

It looks like revisions 3 and 2 in [this answer's revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14450383/revisions) are switched.

From discussing the apparent anomaly with @Rapptz (the author of one of the edits), he confirms that his edit was an "Improve" from the suggestion of @Anusha. The revisions have identical seconds-resolution timestamps as a result.

The [*review* history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1370352) confirms that this occurs and that there should be nothing left to do on the answer; however, the revision history implies that there is still a suggested edit left to review.

---

#### The answer

[image: The answer]

---

#### The revision history

[image: The revision history]

---

#### The review history

[image: The review history]

---

<sub>([It looks like this has happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139625/edit-history-may-become-out-of-order-if-suggested-edit-was-approved-with-improve?rq=1), but that was marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) some six months ago...)</sub>

Comment: +1. It happened to me too. I edited [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1297075). But in [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14210168/revisions) it shows me as second editor (that is wrong). But [in the post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14210168/1369235) it show as edited by me (that is correct)

Comment: @hims056: Glad to see that I'm not losing my mind.

Comment: @hims056: Correction; glad to see that, if I'm losing my mind, it has had no direct effect on my observation of this phenomenon.

Comment: This just happened to me as well: http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/101782/revisions.

Comment: Again [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14563738/revisions)